# Bootstrap popup with scrollbar on body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar

On my page https://itc-ms.de (Delphi/Intraweb/IWBootstrap using bootstrap 3.3.7) I use the css

```
body {
...    
overflow-y: scroll;
...
}
```

to avoid flicker when switching between pages of different length due to the scrollbar appearing and not.

Unfortunately the scrollbar disappears if a bootstrap popup is shown (like my login dialog shown when clicking on "Anmelden").

I already tried

```
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
```

but this does not work as it just applies a scrollbar to the layer above the page body when a pop up is rendered. The page scrollbar still disappears moving the page contents and creating the flicker.

Is there a css way to make the scrollbar of the page body persistent also when a popup is shown?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, just saw this is a duplicate of [Scrollbar is disabled when Bootstrap modal is opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808537/scrollbar-is-disabled-when-bootstrap-modal-is-opened?rq=1). Voted for close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrollbar is disabled when Bootstrap modal is opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808537/scrollbar-is-disabled-when-bootstrap-modal-is-opened)